# Error with deserialization of IFormFile from an Angular nested object

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, iformfile

I was trying to send an object to the API, but I'm getting problems with the deserialization of the File. Everything works if I don't try to send the File inside the FileInfo object.

After some research I found out that I couldn't use either the IFormFile, or FormFile to receive this information and that I should create a View Model to do this.

Those are the objects in Angular and the call to the API

```
export class Stuff{

  id: number;
  info: string;
  filesInfo: FileInfo[]

}

export class FileInfo{

  id: number;
  info: string;
  file: File

}

saveStuff(stuff: Stuff, route: string): Observable<Stuff> {
  return this.http.post<Stuff>(route, stuff);
}
```

This is the API that is receiving this object

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("stuff")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ValidationResult), 400)]
public ActionResult CreateStuff(Stuff stuff)
```

And those are the objects that I'm using to receive the data.

```
public class Stuff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Info{ get; set; }
    public IList<FileInfo> FilesInfo{ get; set; }
}

public class FileInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Info{ get; set; }
    public FormFileViewModel File { get; set; }
}

public class FormFileViewModel : FormFile
{
    public FormFileViewModel(int size, string name) : base(null, 0, size, name, name)
    {

    }
}
```

Even after minimizing the constructor so that it only receives as parameters, values that I know that the File object from angular have it still doesn't work... If I make an empty constructor it does, but it's pointless (I'm interested in the OpenReadStream(), name and ContentType of the FormFile object).

The error I get is:

> Each parameter in constructor 'Void .ctor(Int32, System.String)' on type 'FormFileViewModel' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive.

If there is any other way to do it I would also appreciate it.

Comment: try decorating the constructor with [JsonConstructor]

Comment: @J.Salas it didn't work

Comment: As a short explanation, the JsonDeserializer looks for a constructor decorated with [JsonConstructor], an empty constructor, and nothing else.

Comment: The json you post appears to be lowercase and the classes on the c# side appear to be uppercase.  If you match cases, do the properties get populated?

Comment: @Josh as you can see in the error message, the match can be case-insensitive, also if I remove the File everything works just fine